# asp.net calendar control firing validation controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, calendar

I have a set of validation controls on my asp.net page, to validate values in textfields. I also have a calendar control on the same page. When I click on the calendar image, the validation control message box pops up. How can I avoid that from appearing when the calendar icon is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try to put the calendar control into a different `ValidationGroup` than the other controls.

If it is not in a validation group and the other controls aren't either, try to set a validation group for the other controls.

Comment: The calendar control is not in a validation group. The textboxes and dropdownlist controls have validation, but they are not in a validation group.

Comment: @user279521 - Try to set a validation group for the other controls. (Edited my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use validation groups or if you don't want it to ever trigger validation set CausesValidation = false

Comment: Calendar does not have a causevalidation (as far as I know)